# error: unexpected token get_local. (get_local $lhs)

Tags: rust, webassembly

when I try to use the wat2wasm file.wat command into a simple example like this, it gives me error.

```
(module
(func $add (param $lhs i32) (param $rhs i32) (result i32)
get_local $lhs
get_local $rhs
i32.add)
(export "add" (func $add))
)
```

This is the error:

```
add1.wat:3:5: error: unexpected token get_local, expected ).
    get_local $lhs
    ^^^^^^^^^
add1.wat:4:5: error: unexpected token get_local.
    get_local $rhs

wat2wasm add.wat cmd should run successfully. use one of the wabt tools to generate a wasm module from it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_local` token statement line has to be inside a separate parenthesis, like this:

```
(module
  (func $add (param $lhs i32) (param $rhs i32) (result i32)
    (local.get $lhs)
    (local.get $rhs)
    (i32.add)
  )
  (export "add" (func $add))
)
```

Comment: i tried it ==> but still getting error == >

add.wat:4:9: error: unexpected token "get_local", expected an expr.
       (get_local $lhs)
        ^^^^^^^^^
add.wat:5:9: error: unexpected token get_local.
       (get_local $rhs)
        ^^^^^^^^^
add.wat:9:1: error: unexpected token ), expected EOF.
)

Comment: I get it now, corrected code -- it should be `local.get` and not `get_local`